# Overwrite color and background with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have to change color and background for whole elements in the site. I make it like this:

```js
var color_text = ["initial","#00FF21","#fff"];
var color_background = ["initial","#f00","#000"];
var ile = 1;

$('.kontrast').click(function () {
  $('#main').css("color", color_text[ile]);
  $('#main').css("background", color_background[ile]);
  $('a#main').css("color", color_text[ile]);
  ile = (ile+1) % 3;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="kontrast" href="#">Contrast</a>


<div id="main">
  <h3>A little bit of text </h3>
  <p>z A little bit of text .</p>
  <p><strong>A little bit of text</strong></p>
  <p>A little bit of text</p>
  <p><a href="#">Download .pdf</a></p>
</div>
```

In this case I can't change it for a elements . It doesn't work with h3 elements in my site too. How can I overwrite it for totally all elements? I've tried to do that like this

```
$('a#main').css("color", color_text[ile]);
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: your code is working for <div> right?.you want bg for whole page?

Comment: Yes it is. But if I have 'a' (link) inside it doesn't work for it

Comment: in 'a' tag you dont have "main" id selector. you have main in <div> tag. so it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change jquery selector to "main *"

```js
var color_text = ["initial","#00FF21","#fff"];
var color_background = ["initial","#f00","#000"];
var ile = 1;

$('.kontrast').click(function () {

  $('#main *').css("color", color_text[ile]);
  $('#main *').css("background", color_background[ile]);
  $('a#main').css("color", color_text[ile]);
  ile = (ile+1) % 3;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="kontrast" href="#">Contrast</a>


<div id="main">
  <h3>A little bit of text </h3>
  <p>z A little bit of text .</p>
  <p><strong>A little bit of text</strong></p>
  <p>A little bit of text</p>
  <p><a href="#">Download .pdf</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you change:

```
$('#main').css("background", color_background[ile]);
```

to this:

```
$('body').css("background", color_background[ile]);
```

it will work.

Comment: Yes, but I have to change background and color only in one div, not in whole website